# Solve a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve the following equation $$(4-3i)z^2-25z+31-17i= 0 $$

Dividing by 4-3i gives me $$z^2  \frac{-100z-75zi + 124 + 93i -68i -51i^2}{25}$$ 
which goes to $$z^2 -4z-3zi + 7+i$$

then i collect the terms so $$z - \left(\frac{(4-3i)}{2}\right)^2 = -7 -i + \left(\frac{4-3i}{2}\right)^2$$
and after that i can't get the expansion to work.

Can you help me out?

Comment: use the quadratic formula

Comment: Yeah, use the quadratic formula: a = 1, b = -(4 + 3i), c = 8.

Comment: @addde you got a typo it should be $7+i$ instead of $7+1$

Comment: Are you sure $z$ in the left-hand expression is supposed to be divided by $2$?

Comment: no it should not i spelled it wrong, i have fixed it now.

Comment: Now your $z$ is quite lonely outside the town square.

Comment: And $(-4-3)$ is not the same as $-(4-3)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $z^2−(4+3i)z+7+i=0$

Then

$\Delta=(4+3i)^2−4(7+i)=−21+20i=(2+5i)^2$.

From which one can use the quadratic formula to obtain;

$z=3+4i $ and $z=1−i ...$

Answer (score 2):

Starting from what you ought to have:

$(z−(2+\frac{3}{2}i))^2 = -7-i + (2+\frac{3}{2}i)^2$.

we get:

$(z−(2+\frac{3}{2}i))^2 = -7-i + (4+6i-\frac{9}{4}) = \frac{-21+20i}{4} = (\frac{2+5i}{2})^2$.

The last step I obtained by guessing. If you want a systematic way to find the square root of a complex number if it is a perfect square (the square of a rational complex number) you can use the following technique.

Given $(a+bi)^2 = c+di$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$:

$a^2-b^2 = c$ and $2ab = d$ [by comparing real and imaginary parts].

Thus $4 a^2 - 4 a^2 b^2 = 4 a^2 c^2$ and $4 a^2 b^2 = d^2$ [multiply the first by $2a^2$ and square the second].

Thus $4 a^4 - 4c a^2 - d^2 = 0$ [Add them together to get a quadratic in $a$].

Thus $(2a^2-c)^2 = c^2+d^2$ [Complete the square].

Thus $2a^2-c = \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ and hence $a = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}+c}{2}}$.

Also $2b^2 = 2a^2 - 2c = \sqrt{c^2+d^2}-c$ and hence $b = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}-c}{2}}$.

[Note that the choices of sign are dependent, so it may be better to use $b = \frac{d}{2a}$ instead.]

In the above case we get:

$\sqrt{-21+20i} = \pm \left( \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{21^2+20^2}-21}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{21^2+20^2}+21}{2}} i \right) = \pm (2+5i)$.

[Here I have chosen the signs correctly.]

Comment: @addde: I fixed a minor mistake in my answer and show a way to deterministically obtain the square-root of the complex number. It works in all cases, but if $c,d$ themselves contain surds it may not produce the simplest possible expression. If you are interested in that search for "denesting radicals" here on Math SE.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$(4-3i)z^2-25z+31-17i=0$$ Solving the above quadratic equation for $z$ as follows $$z=\frac{-(-25)\pm\sqrt{(-25)^2-4(4-3i)(31-17i)}}{2(4-3i)}$$
$$z=\frac{-(-25)\pm\sqrt{(-25)^2-4(4-3i)(31-17i)}}{2(4-3i)}$$ $$z=\frac{(4+3i)(25\pm\sqrt{333+644i})}{2(16+9)}$$
$$z=\frac{(4+3i)(25\pm\sqrt{333+644i})}{50}$$
$$z=\frac{(4+3i)\left(25\pm\sqrt{725}\left(\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}+i\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right)}{50}$$ Where, $\alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{333}{725}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{644}{725}\right)$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Could some please explain the reason for what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: I guess the problem is that this answer is in a way too complicated form.

Comment: Yes. you are absolutely right, But at least this may be another option for this question. thanks!

Comment: Np, note that I did not down vote the answer

Comment: No worry, it's not you. But I always like to know some reason I don't care about down vote. I may be wrong so let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start from what you've got

$z^2 -(4+3i)z + 7+i=0$

So

$\Delta=(4+3i)^2-4(7+i)= -21+20i=(2+5i)^2$

Then you can use the formula for the solution of a quadratic equation to get

$z=3+4i\quad $ and $\quad z=1-i$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(4-3i)z^2-25z+31-17i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(4-3i)((7+i)-(4+3i)z+z^2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(4-3i)((7+i)+(-4-3i)z+z^2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(7+i)+(-4-3i)z+z^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z+(-3-4i))((-1+i)+z)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z+(-3-4i)=0 \vee (-1+i)+z=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=3+4i \vee (-1+i)+z=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=3+4i \vee z=1-i$$